# Not able to save data to a new table with composite primary key

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

**Code**

```
require_once 'detect/detect.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');

$fb_id = $_POST['id'];
$full_name = $_POST['name'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$shared = null;
$redeemed = null;

$connection = mysqli_connect("server", "username", "password", "db");

$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO ABC_CAFE (fb_id, full_name, first_name, last_name, email, date_time, shared, redeemed) VALUES ('$fb_id','$full_name','$first_name','$last_name','$email','$date_time','$shared','$redeemed')";

mysqli_close($connection);
```

My table is created with no data.
Primary key is (fb_id,date_time) which is not appearing in the structure.

Comment: Shouldn't you execute a mysqli_query() statement also?

Comment: where you have execute your sql query?

Comment: Sorry, I am not that expert in php. What should I write for mysqli_query() statement?

Comment: Thanks. It works now! But the primary key is not created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mysqli_query() to execute your query.

try this.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("server", "username", "password", "db");
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO ABC_CAFE (fb_id, full_name, first_name, last_name, email, date_time, shared, redeemed) VALUES ('$fb_id','$full_name','$first_name','$last_name','$email','$date_time','$shared','$redeemed')";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now! But the primary key is not created.

Answer (score 2):

Clean way to do it:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("server", "username", "password", "db");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connectiuon Error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO ABC_CAFE (fb_id, full_name, first_name, last_name, email, date_time, shared, redeemed)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param('isssssss', $fb_id, $full_name, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $date_time, $shared, $redeemed);

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Fixed. Thank you !